# localstorage being deleted on jquery get

Tags: jquery, html

my localstorage session values only are being removed when i do a jquery get like such

```
$.get( "/test.html", function( data ) {
  $( ".result" ).html( data );
  alert( "Load was performed." );
});
```

the keys are there but the values are nulled
this is appearing on chrome is this a chrome issue it only seems to be happining when i do a js /jquery get/post request
is there something i am missing? ibve looked ovver documenttion and can fiund no reason why this is happening.

Comment: What's inside of test.html?

Answer (score 0):

Try to minimize your code and see whether you have the same errors. This [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tene1q88/3/) shows that the basic `get` works on Chrome.

```
jQuery.get( '/echo/js/?js=hello%20world!', function( data ) {
   jQuery( ".result" ).html( data );
   alert( "Load was performed. data: " + data );
});
```

There might be a mistake somewhere else in your code. How do you set and get Local Storage?